# Is biology affected by gravity?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, biology

I have a question about time. Let's be hypothetical. Let's assume that we have 2 persons in separated parts of the Universe. One is on Earth, and the other one is on a planet on another side of the Galaxy, and it's on orbit of a massive black hole, but not on a point that it's actually dangerous, but it's gravity deeply  affects life on that planet. 100 years pass. Will both of the persons be dead, or the one near the black hole still be alive ? To me that doesn't make any sense. And, for clarification, i'm not saying that "100 years passed on Earth", i mean they both experience the same amount of "life".
What i'm asking is, is biology affected by this ? or will they both die at the same time ? assuming they have the same life span. I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, to me it is, because to me it is "obvious" that they will die at the same time, but you never know.. Btw if this type of question is off topic of whatever, i have 0 problems in deleting it. Thanks!!!

Comment: In your example assuming the biological systems (I’ll call them twins) die on their 100th birthday, both individuals die on their 100th birthday.  An observer on Earth watching the twin near the black hole would disagree, and say the black hole individual lived for 1000 years or what have you, but in the local frame of the black hole adjacent twin he’d live 100 years by his own measure.

Comment: hmm that's what i thought, thanks man!!!

Comment: @JPattarini Please consider expanding your comment into an answer.